# What could cause Terraform to "forget" that it's already managing a resource it created?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am deploying a simple infrastructure to Azure with Terraform via a CI pipeline in DevOps.

`terraform init`, `terraform plan`, and `terraform apply` run, and for the first run, everything works fine.

When I add a subsequent resource, `apply` fails with similar errors as this:

```
│ Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/578e0f86-0491-4137-9a4e-3a3c0ff28e91/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/stihldevlift-cluster" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" for more information.
```

Terraform *just* created this resource in the run before. What's causing it to forget that and to treat the resource like it already existed and needs to be imported?

Note: I am on Azure, and per security policy, we're required to have on `skip_provider_registration = true.` I don't know if this is causing issues.

In similar questions the "fix" has been to simply destroy everything and start over. I do not have that luxury. I need to understand why it's happening and how to fix it in place. These are production resources.

Interestingly, I can spin all this up in a separate dev space, and I can reproduce the error. When I remove the resources in question, `terraform apply` does recognize them and deletes them accordingly. So does that mean it's a false positive. even if it is, the errors are stopping by CI/CD process.

Here is a full dump of the pipeline errors.

```
 Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/0-0491-4137-9a4e-3a3c0ff28e91/resourceGroups/DEV-Lift_test-Dev_CentralUS/providers/Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions/ContainerInsights(testdevliftLogAnalyticsWorkspace-12879201083717606753)" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" for more information.
 
   with azurerm_log_analytics_solution.container_insights,
   on 02-aks-container-insights.tf line 19, in resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "container_insights":
   19: resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "container_insights" {
 

##[error]Terraform command 'apply' failed with exit code '1'.
##[error]╷
 Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/0-0491-4137-9a4e-3a3c0ff28e91/resourceGroups/DEV-Lift_test-Dev_CentralUS/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/testdevlift-cluster" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" for more information.
 
   with azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s,
   on 02-aks-cluster-definition.tf line 4, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s":
    4: resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
 


╷
 Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/0-0491-4137-9a4e-3a3c0ff28e91/resourceGroups/DEV-Lift_test-Dev_CentralUS/providers/Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions/ContainerInsights(testdevliftLogAnalyticsWorkspace-12879201083717606753)" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" for more information.
 
   with azurerm_log_analytics_solution.container_insights,
   on 02-aks-container-insights.tf line 19, in resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "container_insights":
   19: resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "container_insights" {
```

Comment: In the question you state you are "adding" a resource, but also that you already are managing that same resource. Is the resource added to the config or does it already exist in the config? Also, are you seeing this error for all resources, or for  a subset of the resources?

Comment: Another thing you can try is to set an environment variable `TF_LOG` to an appropriate level e.g. DEBUG, which may help giving insight into what specifically is happening. While you may not want to delete this set of resources, maybe you can create another set and run this log level which could provide more insight. https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging

Comment: @MattSchuchard Sorry for the confusion. I've published the manifests since it's a little much to add here. Also, what I mean about re-adding. I have to do an initial apply to get the core infrastructure up and running. Per terraform, the kubernetes_manifests need to be applied in a subsequent apply. It's when I do this that I get the errors that these resources exist and need importing. Most have to do with file 02, but here they all are for reference. https://github.com/blue928/demoterraform

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the logs from the first run that created the resource it is hard to say.

One thing to note though is that behind the scenes some complex resources require multiple API calls to get created. If one of those API calls fails resources still get created in the cloud, but they may not make it into the state file. This typically happens when there's a permissions error (one of the API calls isn't allowed) or a timeout of some sort.

When this happens you can manually delete just the resource that is conflicting, or you can import that resource into the state and do another terraform apply to finish configuring it.

This should be a fairly rare occurrence though, and the logs from the initial run should help you identify what the root cause was.